Scott Twinloc - Fit4 topcap removal
The remote lockout on my Scott Spark's fork (Fox Performance 32 SC with twinloc) has stopped working - the lockout does not return to open after releasing it. I wanted to service the spring to solve this.
However, I can't figure out how to remove the top cap.
I tried to loosen the bolt in the middle, but that only lead to it stripping.
So my questions are:
a) What would be the correct way to remove the top cap
b) if that involves the bolt in the middle, any ideas how to loosen it while stripped?

